# How to store Date only, not DateTime

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As can see on the picture bellow, how can I store Date only on Firestore?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, then you can call [`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString), example:

```
let date = new Date();
console.log(date.toDateString());
```

should give you:

> "Wed Jun 23 2021"

Then you can do:

```
await reference.set({birthdate : date})
```

Comment: Actually I am storing the result of this function (which returns a Date) https://pastebin.com/Ume4s9dg

Comment: yes, `toDateString()` is a function under the `Date` prototype so all you need to do is to call it